# separating only suffixes from string

Tags: python, suffix

I have a list of word suffixes, my aim is to separate the entered sentence into suffixes in the list.

My problem is that the suffixes in this list separate the words even at the root. For instance:

(internationally) >> should be >> (interna _tion _al _ly), my code's output is >> (int _erna _tion _al _ly)

Note: I have "er" in my list

One solution could be to search for words starting from the end of the sentence. For example, the code first adds the letter "y" if it matches the list, separates it, if it doesn't it continues to add > "ly" separates because it matches, then resets and continues "l" > "al" and separates it and continues. If it continues like this, "erna" won't match and split.

If it searches this way the problem goes away but I couldn't find how to do it.

I would be very happy if you show me the way.

```
sentence = input()
suffixes = ["acy", "ance", "ence", "dom", "er", "or", "ism", "ist",
         "ty", "ment", "ness", "ship", "sion", "tion", "ate",
        "en", "fy", "ize", "able", "ible", "al",
        "esque", "ful", "ic", "ous", "ish", "ive",
        "less", "ed", "ing", "ly", "ward", "wise"]

for x in suffixes:
    y = " _" + x
    sentence = sentence.replace(x, y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including input (list of suffixes) and code. Even if you're not looking for debugging help per se, you at least need to provide the list of suffixes. For example, I don't know where you're getting `tion` from, since the root is "nation", not "na".

Comment: shouldn't internationally be international ly?

Comment: @Matiiss "international" has a suffix itself, "al". That said, I don't know why "tion" is counted as a suffix, like I wrote above.

Comment: kinda hard to tell ... without seeing Your code, how do You think I will know why it is counted as a suffix without seeing Your code?

Comment: @Matiiss Actually, maybe you're right. "al" is attached to "nation", not "*internation".

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add codes, added now

Comment: This is not a free coding service.  Nor is it a place for "showing the way."  Ask a specific, code-related question next time.

Comment: @TomServo "next time"? I think this could be turned into a good question. Maybe "How do I match multiple suffixes on a word?"

Comment: I would reverse both the input and the suffixes and then use re.match to do prefix matching and then move forward and repeat while there is a suffix found.

Comment: @wjandrea Perhaps you're right, but it's a hard problem as your single example above shows, and many OPs don't improve their questions.  Too many people give substantive clues in comments instead of answers and most OPs just disappear.

Comment: Anybody with enough rep can edit the question if he/she thinks it can be improved on. It doesn't have to be the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `endswith()` and string slicing:

```py
suffixes = ["acy", "ance", "ence", "dom", "er", "or", "ism", "ist",
            "ty", "ment", "ness", "ship", "sion", "tion", "ate",
            "en", "fy", "ize", "able", "ible", "al",
            "esque", "ful", "ic", "ous", "ish", "ive",
            "less", "ed", "ing", "ly", "ward", "wise"]

def find_suffix(word):
    for suffix in suffixes:
        if word.endswith(suffix):
            suffix_removed = word[:-len(suffix)] # part before suffix
            return find_suffix(suffix_removed) + f' _{suffix}' # recurse
    return word # if no suffix is found, return the word as is

print(find_suffix('internationally')) # interna _tion _al _ly
print(find_suffix('egoistically')) # ego _ist _ic _al _ly
```

Recursion is not essential; the same can be done just with a `for` loop.

In Python 3.9, [they introduced a method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) `removesuffix()` for string, which is defined basically in the same way as  the code above. If you are using Python 3.9+, you can instead use `suffix_removed = word.removesuffix(suffix)` for readability (although I have not tested this since I use 3.8).

---

Per OP's request, the following is a function that applies the above to each word in a sentence.

```py
def suffixify_sentence(sentence):
    return ' '.join(find_suffix(word) for word in sentence.split())

sentence = 'humanity internationally faithfully picturesque'
print(suffixify_sentence(sentence)) # humani _ty interna _tion _al _ly faith _ful _ly pictur _esque
```

Comment: Beside the point, but `suffixes` should be a parameter

Comment: Interesting, is there any benefit to doing this type of problem recursively?

Comment: @fthomson FWIW, it's more elegant than [my iterative solution](/a/68027602/4518341) :)

Comment: Recursive solutions tend to be concise so there is something to be said for that. I thought  I was getting fancy building it backwards lol

Comment: @j1-lee what if we wanted to do this for a sentence instead of a word?

Comment: @j1-lee Yes, it should be applied to every word in the sentence.
I can give an example: "humanity internatIonally faithfully picturesque" >> "humani _ty interna _tIon _al _ly faith _ful _ly pictur _esque"

Comment: @j1-lee Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace()` is the problem. It replaces the substring *anywhere*, not just at the end. Instead you can use [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) or if you're using 3.9+, [`str.removesuffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix).

Here's an iterative implementation using `str.endswith()`.

```
def remove_suffixes(string, suffixes):
    """
    Remove all suffixes from string. Return the root and suffixes.

    >>> remove_suffixes('smartly', ['y', 'ly'])
    ('smart', ['ly'])
    """
    # Sort to ensure the longest ones match first
    suffixes = sorted(suffixes, key=len, reverse=True)
    removed = []
    prev = None  # Loop variable
    while prev != string:  # i.e. break if unchanged
        prev = string  # Copy for next loop
        for suffix in suffixes:
            if string.endswith(suffix):
                removed.append(suffix)
                string = string[:-len(suffix)]
    return string, removed[::-1]

suffixes = [
    "acy", "ance", "ence", "dom", "er", "or", "ism", "ist",
    "ty", "ment", "ness", "ship", "sion", "tion", "ate",
    "en", "fy", "ize", "able", "ible", "al",
    "esque", "ful", "ic", "ous", "ish", "ive",
    "less", "ed", "ing", "ly", "ward", "wise"]

s_out, found = remove_suffixes('internationally', suffixes)
# > 'interna', ['tion', 'al', 'ly']
print(s_out, *found, sep=' _')  # -> interna _tion _al _ly
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your algorithm will work in all cases but it seemed fun to implement so here it is

```
sentence = 'internationally'
sentence = list(sentence)
stack = []
results = []
for i in sentence[::-1]:
    stack.insert(0,i)
    guess = ''.join(stack)
    if guess in suffixes:
        results.insert(0, f'_{guess}')
        stack = []

results.insert(0, guess)
    
print(''.join(results))
# interna_tion_al_ly
```

you essentially implement a stack and build it backwards

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
max_length = max(len(suffix) for suffix in suffixes)
for suffix_length in range(max_length):
    if suffix_length >= len(word):
        break
    if word[-suffix_length:] in suffixes:
        #split suffix
```

Another tactic is to iterate through the suffixes in increasing length. You can do this by having `suffixes = sorted(suffixes, key = len)` before iterating through the suffixes. I.e.:

```
sentence = input()
suffixes = ["acy", "ance", "ence", "dom", "er", "or", "ism", "ist",
     "ty", "ment", "ness", "ship", "sion", "tion", "ate",
    "en", "fy", "ize", "able", "ible", "al",
    "esque", "ful", "ic", "ous", "ish", "ive",
    "less", "ed", "ing", "ly", "ward", "wise"]

suffixes = sorted(suffixes, key = len)
for x in suffixes:
    y = " _" + x
    sentence = sentence.replace(x, y)
```

Comment: second tactic doesn't work, try "freedomwise", output is "fre _e _dom _wise", it should be "free _dom _wise"